# Integration by parts on manifold with corners

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, integration

Suppose that $M$ is a compact manifold with corners, where each boundary hypersurface is an embedded submanifold. Then, do we have an integration by parts identity? i.e.
\begin{align*}
\int_M g(\nabla f, X) \,d\textrm{vol} = \int_{\partial M} f\left\langle X,N \right\rangle \,d\textrm{vol}_{\tilde{g}} - \int_M f\cdot (\operatorname{div} X ) \,d\textrm{vol}
\end{align*}
with $f\in C^\infty(M), X\in \Gamma(M,TM)$. I know that this identity hold for domains with lipschitz boundary, but it is not very clear to me if a domain with corners is a special case of a lipschitz domain.

Comment: Proving this identity on a manifold with corners is quite straightforward using a partition of unity and local coordinates. Citing a theorem about domains with Lipschitz boundary seems unnecessary to me.

Comment: ^Especially since corners are measure 0 points.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can treat manifolds with corners as Lipschitz domains.

By definition of a manifold with corners $M$, for any $p \in \partial M$, there is a smooth coordinate map sending a neighbourhood of $p$ to a subset of $R:=(\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0})^n$. Then $x \mapsto \min_i x_i$ is a Lipschitz map which is positive inside $R$ and negative outside it.

Comment: I found a theorem statement in Mikhail S. Agranovich's *Sobolev Spaces, Their Generalizations, and Elliptic Problems in Smooth and Lipschitz Domains*. There may be better ones out there, please leave a comment if you know of any.

Comment: I've corrected it now.